# How can I show a pdf file (binary[]) in System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser of WPF desktop app?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

PDF files are saved in a SQL Server database as `byte[]`. After I get `binary[]` from the database and save it as a local file, this code works:

```
string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
string fileName = tempPath + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssFFF") + ".pdf";
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, binary[]);
WebBrowser.Navigate(fileName).
```

If I directly pass the `binary[]` to `WebBrowser.NavigateToStream()`, it shows raw pdf strings:

```
WebBrowser.NavigateToStream(binary[]).
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a temporary file after you receive `byte[]` data from database.

```
byte[] fileBytes = // YOUR LOGIC TO READ byte[] FROM DATABASE

string tempFile = @"C:\temp\abc.pdf";

File.WriteAllBytes(tempFile, fileBytes);

myBrowser.Source = new Uri(tempFile);
```

After use, you can delete temporary file that you created.

Comment: Yes, in this case, sometimes the process holds temporary files and is not able to delete them. Is there no way to directly show binary/stream data?

Comment: It won't create any issue if you handle file access properly in code.

Comment: Theoretically right, but simple is the best and can reduce the cause of a bug. 
Is there no way to show binary/stream data?